# Python Raspberry Pi Piano-HAT Permission denied

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, hardware

I recently bought myself a Piano HAT to place on my Rasberry Pi. I am using this website to help me get started, however I have run into an issue...
http://learn.pimoroni.com/tutorial/piano-hat/getting-started-with-piano-hat
When I first ran the program (Under Your First Piano HAT), I encountered a lengthy error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File"/home/pi/My-First-Piano-HAT.py", line 1, in <module>

import pianohat

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pianohat.py", line 103 in <module>

_piano_ctog = caplxxx.Cap1188(i2c_addr=0X28, alery pin=4)

File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/caplxxx.py", line 239, in__init__

self.ic2             = SMBus(i2c_bus)

IOError:[Errno 13} Permission denied

_________________________________________________________________________
```

---

If you could answer this question, and solve it for me, I would really appreciate it, as this problem has had me vexed for most of the day :-/

Thanks

Also, I **have** typed curl "-sSL get.pimoroni.com/pianohat | bash" into the terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to fix the access permissions to the I2C devices.
How that is done depends on the Linux version you're using. See e.g. [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=238003).

If you are the only user of this device, you can set the permissions for these devices to include world readable/writeable (mode 666).

From a security standpoint, it would be better to create a dedicated group (e.g. `i2c` or `devices`), set that group as the group of the device nodes in question (making them group readable/writable) and add yourself as a member of that group.